# Why does Visual Studio not format binary operator * correctly?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, formatting

I noticed that the `Format Document` command within Visual Studio (Express 2015) does not correctly format the following statement, even though I have `Insert spaces before and after binary operators` set:

Input (and output):

```
int a, b, c;
a = b*c;
```

Expected Formatting:

```
int a, b, c;
a = b * c;
```

---

If I instead try to format a statement with a numeric component, I get the expected formatting.

Input:

```
int a, b;
a = b*8;
```

Output:

```
int a, b;
a = b * 8;
```

Other operators work correctly, such as `-`, `+`, and `/`. I also noticed that `%` behaves like `*`. Why does this happen, and how can I get the behavior I want?

---

As a side note, I originally discovered this when working with C-Style casts. Visual Studio actually removes the spaces between the operator for statements like `a = (int)(b) + c;`, and generally does nothing when the `*` operator is used. It does the expected behavior when the statement is presented like `a = (int)b + c;` or `a = int(b) + c;`.

Comment: Looks like a bug.

Comment: Maybe because `*` is treated as `pointer` when it is with characters and not digits? Not sure about the `%`

Comment: @KyleKhalaf I had the same first thought, but as I was trying different operators, the `%` made me wonder otherwise.

Comment: @KyleKhalaf, the `*` pointer operator is not binary, so the difference is clearly stated in the syntax of the language.  You only have to see if there are operators at both sides, and you'll get a binary operator.